# why youtube music video not working properly in iframe tag

Tags: html, css

Please try to run once in local machine to see the exact problem

**Screenshot:**
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S76snYXHQcE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <!-- Music video -->

    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kffacxfA7G4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AFAIK YouTube won't let you embed copyrighted material (and that video is)

Answer (score 0):

they just protect few videos to be read out of youtube.xxx with a server configuration. Something like this apache .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!^$"
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!www.example.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "\.(gif|jpg|png)$"    "-"   [F,NC]
```

this is what we use to protect pictures :Description:
The following technique forbids the practice of other sites including your images inline in their pages. This practice is often referred to as "hotlinking", and results in your bandwidth being used to serve content for someone else's site. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html